# Laravel 4 Redis Session Connection

Tags: php, session, redis, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the Laravel Redis session driver, 
Problem is - It seems to always assume usage of the "default" connection. Does anyone know if its possible to use a different connection ?

For example "session" ? So all my session would be on one server?

Also, whenever I don't have a "default" key in the redis array, i get exceptions all over the place. Must I declare a "default" connection ? What's wrong with having my own names?

e.g.

[image: Redis connections]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way of doing what you want. The Redis based session driver uses the Redis based cache driver:

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Cache.RedisStore.html#5-155

Unfortunately that doesn't provide any way to specify which connection to use - it just uses the default connection:

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Redis.Database.html#3-96

(magic method calls to the above class go straight to the default connection)

A possible way to get what you want might be to write your own class that extends RedisStore with a constructor that takes in a connection name and sets `$this->redis` to whatever `Redis::connection($name)` returns. You'd also need to figure out how to get the session handler to use your own cache driver though. I don't know how easy it would be or how you'd do that - it might be difficult to try and wire it all up.

Comment: I think I'm just gonna have the "default" connection for the sessions, and then use specifiec "named" connections for the rest of my data... Ugly solution but I don't see an easier option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this:
I will outline why you were getting errors and how to fix this the simple way (incase someone else has the same issue):

- open at vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Redis/Database.php
- create a $name variable for your connection at the top of the class

  class Database {

  ```
  /**
   * The host address of the database.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $clients;
  protected $name;
  ```
- change the connection function to expect your own 'default' fallback and 'set the name' of your current connection.

  [image: (sorry could not get this bit of code to format properly hence the Screen Shot)]
- on the command method you will need to provide your 'new connection name' ($this->name) instead of the default one.

[image]

that's it!

now from anywhere in the application you can use the 'Redis' facade to access your connections just like this:

```
REDIS::CONNECTION('small');
REDIS::CONNECTION('large');
REDIS::CONNECTION('session');
REDIS::CONNECTION('etc');
```

Comment: That's tricky and I'm not sure even best practice. You're modifying the original framework ... Meaning when you need to upgrade... Sucks for you :)

Comment: Hey @ShaiMishali, probably not best practise, but surely is the 'simplest/easiest' way to get it done, based on the question I figured the level of expertise and answered appropriately.
Also from my answer above is easy enough to figure out how to 'add your own providers' and edit whatever needs to be modified so it makes upgrading easier in the future.

Answer (score -3):

Change the session driver in Config\session.php from native to redis

Comment: Bad answer. This isn't what I'm asking. I asked how do I make sure the driver uses a specific named connection. Not how to *generally* use the redis driver.